# Custom configuration of Spark partition discovery

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I understand that Spark supports [partition discovery](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html#partition-discovery), where directories names follow fixed pattern of column_name=column_value. Example from the linked webpage:

> `path -> to -> table -> gender=male -> country=US -> data.parquet`

I would like to use this functionality, but unfortunately the file structure that I'm currently working on does not follow this pattern. I can't change it and converting it is not feasible. In my case the directories are purely column values, as in:

`path -> to -> table -> male -> US -> data.parquet`

Ideally I would like to configure Spark to indicate that the sub-directories of "table" directory contain "gender", followed by "country" sub-directory and so on.

I'm using Spark 2.11 from Java. I'm also using Parquet files.

Comment: I have a similar question. Do you mind sharing your final solution?

Comment: I couldn't make it work with partition discovery. In my case I knew the shape of the most critical/heavy query, so I optimised it by creating a custom data set. Going back to the example, I was able to detect if only a single country was requested and then I recursively scanned the directories  to only include the relevant directories (ex: US).

Comment: thanks for the info. I bypassed the problem by changing my directory layout